# no queue 'dev_pms2invoi_queue' in vhost '/' when using rabbitmq in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want to use rabbitmq in spring-boot project just using annotations, Here is my mq config code,

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {
    @Bean(value = "pmsMqConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory pmsMqConnectionFactory(){
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(pmsMqServerAddress);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(pmsMqServerVirtualHost);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(pmsMqServerUserName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(pmsMqServerPassword);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    @Bean(value = "pmsConsumerQueue")
    public Queue pmsConsumerQueue(){
        Queue consumerQueue=new Queue(pmsMqConsumerQueue,pmsMqQueuePersist);

        return consumerQueue;
    }
    @Bean(value = "pmsConsumerExchange")
    public Exchange pmsConsumerExchange(){
        Exchange consumerExchange=new DirectExchange(pmsMqConsumerExchangeName,pmsMqQueuePersist,false);
        return consumerExchange;
    }
    @Bean(value = "pmsConsumerMessageBinding")
    public Binding pmsConsumerMessageBinding(@Qualifier("pmsConsumerQueue") Queue queue,
                                                  @Qualifier("pmsConsumerExchange") Exchange exchange){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("").noargs();
    }
    @Bean(value = "pmsMessageListenerContainer")
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer pmsMessageListenerContainer(@Qualifier("pmsMqConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                      @Qualifier("pmsMqConsumer") PmsMqConsumer pmsMqConsumer,@Qualifier("pmsConsumerQueue")Queue queue){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container=new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageListener(pmsMqConsumer);
        container.setQueues(queue);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        return container;
    }
}
```

When i start the application, error happens:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[dev_pms2invoi_queue]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:636)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1389)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:615)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'dev_pms2invoi_queue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at
```

It says that there is no queue, but how to create it with annotation? Is there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared your own connection factory, you need to declare a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` that uses that connection factory.

If you use boot's property-driven configuration, it will auto-configure a connection factory and `RabbitAdmin` for you.

Comment: it works, if i have multi own connection factory (that is multi mq server), so i have to declare multi RabbitAdmin?

Comment: Yes, but [see the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#conditional-declaration) - you can indicate which admin(s) should declare which queue(s) using `setAdminsThatShouldDeclare()`, or all admins, if you want all queues on all brokers.